# Running SQL Server query using c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code :

```
Connection c = new Connection();

string select1 =      
   @"SELECT 
       E.employeeNumber AS 'Employee Number', 
       E.employeePrivateName + ' ' + E.employeeFamilyName AS 'Employee Name', 
       DATEDIFF (MONTH, E.startWorkingDate, GETDATE()) AS 'Seniority in Month', 
       M.machineName AS 'Machine Name', J.jobName AS 'Job Name', 
       COUNT(E.employeeNumber) AS 'Number of Times on Machine in Specif Job', 
       SUM(Number_Of_Days_During_The_Period) AS 'Total Working Days on Machine in Specif Job', 
       SUM(Salary_per_Period) AS 'The Salary For working on Machine in Specif Job' 
    FROM 
       TblEmployee E 
    INNER JOIN 
       AllSchedules A_S on E.employeeNumber = A_S.employeeNumber 
    INNER JOIN 
       TblJob J on J.jobNumber = A_S.jobNumber 
    INNER JOIN 
       TblMachine M on M.machineNumber = A_S.machineNumber 
    INNER JOIN 
       TblPeriod P on P.Number = A_S.periodNumber 
    WHERE 
       Month(P.fromDate) = Month(@Month) 
    GROUP BY 
       E.employeeNumber, E.employeePrivateName, E.employeeFamilyName, 
       E.startWorkingDate, M.machineName, J.jobName 
    ORDER BY 
       E.employeeFamilyName , E.employeePrivateName";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select1, c.con);
DateTime month = comboBox1.Text;

cmd.Connection = c.con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", month);

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); //c.con is the      connection string

SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

I want to run the query, however I need to define a datetime value so it would be a search parameter for the query. How do I save the DateTime variable so that it will hold a month number (10 for october, etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
string monthString = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox1.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month.ToString("MM");
```

and to convert it to an integer:

```
int month = int.Parse(monthString);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your query you have this line for the WHERE condition

```
WHERE Month(P.fromDate)= Month(@Month)
```

THe [MONTH function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187813%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) of T-SQL expects to receive a Date for its parameter, so you probably need only

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, month, 1);
```

and pass this value for the parameter `@Month`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", dt);
```

EDIT: If you have a combobox with items filled with the month names ordered: (January, February....)

```
// In array the indexes start at zero.....
if(cboMonths.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    int month = cboMonts.SelectedIndex + 1;

}
```

Comment: I want the user to select the month number from the combobox and pass it as a parameter to the query

Comment: Seeing you have accepted an answer that clearly fails when you pass that month value to the query. Could you tell me what is the content of comboBox1?

Comment: I used several parts of your answer, and It worked for me. the part before your edit helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
string sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the SQL `Month` function returns an integer ([Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)) you need to replace:

```
"... WHERE Month(P.fromDate)= Month(@Month) GROUP BY ..."
```

by

```
"... WHERE Month(P.fromDate) = " + intMonth.ToString() + " GROUP BY ..."
```

where `intMonth` is the integer value of the month selected from your combobox.

However, you will need to make sure that it is just an integer and can't be used as an injection attack. You would be better off putting all your SQL into a stored procedure and passing the month as an integer parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't you use parameters for the query string?

Comment: @Pacane - Isn't that what I said in the second half of the answer>